# What is a good intermediate introduction to Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to find a resource where I can practice my programming skills in scheme.

I have a class coming up that uses scheme exclusively. While I have done moderate amounts of programming in C++ and Java, and grasp the basic ideas about good/bad programming practices and different programming paradigms (as much as a second-year college student could be expected to), Scheme looks like hieroglyphics to me!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for an *intermediate* introduction, SICP will *not* be a good choice.  You could try [HtDP](http://htdp.org/), but that not too much of an intro to Scheme as it is an intro to programming in general.

Comment: I acutally plan on getting the Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs once I have a handle on Shceme because it seems to be an integral part of the cannon of CompSci literature. How to Design Programs is talking slightly down to me, but I like the number of example problems, so I'll try it out! Thanks!

Comment: Doing HtDP before SICP is definitely a good idea.  SICP definitely has some good bits, but it generally uses lots of examples that require knowing other things well (something that HtDP avoids very intentionally).

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't looked at [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) yet, that's the obvious (and free!) place to start.

Answer (score 6):

I really like [The Little Schemer](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=4825). The format is very different, but it all builds up from basics.

Answer (score 4):

[The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/), 4th Edition (Covers the language as described in R6RS.).
If you are using a Scheme that conforms only with R5RS, use the [3rd edition](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/) of the book.

Answer (score 1):

Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The Guide to Racket http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html is a good place to find the information you need. It has a  very good navigation system and many simple examples. You can use it with SICP.